Terraform - iterate a list within a map variable
I am running through an issue that I need help with. I have this variable structure:
variable "dns" {
  type = map(object({
  name     = string
  hostname = string
  dns_ips  = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "server1" = {
      pretty_name  = "Server One"
      hostname = "vm-01"
      dns_ips      = ["128.0.0.8", "128.0.0.9", "128.0.0.10"]
    }
    "server2" = {
      pretty_name  = "Server Two"
      isp_hostname = "vm-01"
      dns_ips      = ["129.0.0.8", "129.0.0.9", "129.0.0.10", "129.0.0.11"]
    }
  }
}

I want to create a resource "datadog_synthetic_test" which create a DNS test for each of the server.
I want to create multiple resources with for_each. My end goal is 7 resources:

vm1, ip1
vm1, ip2
vm1, ip3
vm2, ip1
vm2, ip2
vm2, ip3
vm2, ip4

I know that I need to use flatten but I can't figure it out.
Resource example:
resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "dns_test" {
  for_each = {
    for server_name, server_info in var.dns : server_name => server_info.dns_ips
  }
  name = "${var.synthetic_prefix} ${each.key} - Resolve @${dns_ip.value}"
  request_definition {
    dns_server              = dns_ip.value
    dns_server_port         = 0
    host                    = var.dns_domain_name[0]
    no_saving_response_body = false
    number_of_packets       = 0
    port                    = 0
    should_track_hops       = false
    timeout                 = 0
  }
}

I tried using for_each as above, I tried to implement flatten but the end result was that an error occurred for

each.value is list of string with 3 elements


I cannot test this with the DataDog provider, but using a combination of built-in functions like flatten and merge along with for_each meta-argument should work. For example:
locals {
  dd_dns = merge(flatten([
    for server_name, server_info in var.dns : {
      for ns in server_info.dns_ips :
      ns => {
        server_name = server_name
        dns_ip      = ns
      }
  }])...) # ... is the ellipsis operator in terraform, do not remove it
}

resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "dns_test" {
  for_each = local.dd_dns
  name = "${var.synthetic_prefix} ${each.value.server_name} - Resolve @${each.value.dns_ip}"
  request_definition {
    dns_server              = each.value.dns_ip
    dns_server_port         = 0
    host                    = var.dns_domain_name[0]
    no_saving_response_body = false
    number_of_packets       = 0
    port                    = 0
    should_track_hops       = false
    timeout                 = 0
  }
}

The key thing to note here is that the DNS IP addresses have all to be unique for this to work as you want it.

Thank you for a quick reply.
This works great! Thank you. I am missing something though. I am also trying to regexp something called "private location" as a Datadog feature. This allows to ping from a specific location as well. And because of locals and for each I cannot use hostname to regexp. Can you help me add this?
locations = [
    for location, info in data.datadog_synthetics_locations.private_locations.locations :
    location if can(regex("pl:${each.value.isp_hostname}-.*", location))
  ]


With this I get an error: Error: error creating synthetics API test from https://api.datadoghq.eu/api/v1/synthetics/tests/api: 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["'locations' should be array"]}

If this did help, please consider accepting the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979. For your other comments, that's a completely different question compared to the original one so you can ask another.

From your terraform configuration and what you’re trying to achieve(to create a datadog_synthetics_test resource for each server and IP combination), you need to use a combination of flatten and for to correctly format your for_each statement.
I’ll suggest that you adjust the structure of your for_each to properly flatten and iterate over each server-IP pair. Something like :
resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "dns_test" {
  for_each = {
    for server, config in var.dns : server => flatten([
      for ip in config.dns_ips : {
        hostname = config.hostname
        ip       = ip
      }
    ])
  }

  name = "${each.key} - Resolve @${each.value.ip}"

  request_definition {
    dns_server = each.value.ip
    host       = each.value.hostname
  }
}

This config uses flatten to convert the list of IPs for each server into a flat list where each item is a map containing the hostname and an individual IP.
The for_each attribute uses the flattened structure so that each server-IP pair becomes a unique instance of the resource.
This setup allows you to create a datadog_synthetics_test for each IP address associated with each server, as required. Adjust the remaining settings in request_definition as needed for your specific use case.

Thank you for a quick reply. Unfortunately this does not work.
It throws an error that tuple has 3 or 4 elements, depending on a variable.
